# One of the following lines is breaking my Media Page

Tags: wordpress

One of the following lines is breaking my media page in the admin panel.

```
// adds the page to the wp admin panel
add_action("admin_menu", "lec_add_page");               // runs lec_add_page()

// adds the page to the top menu level on the admin panel
function lec_add_page() {

add_menu_page("Live Events Calendar", "Live Events Calendar", "manage_options", "live-events-calendar-admin.php", "lec_create_page", plugins_url("live-events-calendar/images/calendar.png"));

}

// building the page
function lec_create_page() { ?>
<?php echo "Admin Page Test"; ?>
<?php } ?><!-- END lec_create_page() -->
```

It is ether the add_action("admin_menu"... or the add_menu_page(... lines.  I am sure I have them right. I have looked at other plug ins I have active and they have the same lines implemented in the same way and they do not interfere with the media page.

On the media page it self, it defaults to grid when it loads and looks like it is continuously loading (spinning ball) an no images show. If I click on list view then it loads all the images, but clicking on grid view again still just sits there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Oh and WP 4.1.1 if that helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The **menu slug** should have the name of your plugin, something like "**myplugin/live-events-calendar-admin.php**". Here is the code from **codex**

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );

function register_my_custom_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page( 'custom menu title', 'custom menu', 'manage_options', 'custompage', 'my_custom_menu_page', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ), 6 ); 
}

function my_custom_menu_page(){
    echo "Admin Page Test"; 
}
```